# How to delete an item from object

Tags: javascript, object, datatables

I'm using datatables and importer CSV file to fill a table and fill a **hidden input**

I'm trying to delete an item when I press the delete button from the table, at the moment I have this

```
        $('#task-place-table tbody').on('click', '.deleted', function () {
            dataTable
                .row($(this).parents('tr'))
                .remove()
                .draw();
            itemCounter--;
            document.getElementById('item-counter').value = itemCounter;
        });
```

[image]

this code can delete the item from the table, **but not from the hidden input**

for example, this is the input

```
[{"url":"http://www.restaurant.com","businessTypeId":"1"},{"url":"http://www.hotel.com","businessTypeId":"2"},{"url":"http://www.test.com","businessTypeId":"3"}]
```

In the example, I deleted restaurant and test item, but in the hidden input, the items still remain there (**NOTE: businessTypeId is not the row ID**)

I would like to have this when I delete an item from the table

```
[{"url":"http://www.hotel.com","businessTypeId":"2"}]
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE: businessTypeId is not the row ID or Item ID, number 2 is coincidence (that number is the ID in database)**

how can I delete items?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a reference to the hidden input.
2. Modify the value array for that hidden input.

i.e:

```
// "3" being the 'id' of the deleted item(s)
hiddenInputHandle.value = hiddenInputHandle.value.filter(i->i.businessTypeId !== "3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution, with splice and a for, to loop through the array, I can clear the data taking url as reference

```
        $('#task-place-table tbody').on('click', '.deleted', function () {
            let value = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).text();
                for (let i = 0; i < placesArray.length; i++) {
                    if (placesArray[i].url == value) {
                        placesArray.splice(i, 1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                $('#places').val(JSON.stringify(placesArray));

            dataTable
                .row($(this).parents('tr'))
                .remove()
                .draw();
            itemCounter--;
            document.getElementById('item-counter').value = itemCounter;
        });
```

Comment: Cuellar Avaroma, please, always endeavour to add an explanation on your code. You could most importantly add a reason why your code solves the problem.